# return the number that occur only once in a array python

Tags: python-2.7

I have an array `[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4]` and I would like to return 5, 6.

If I use `set(my_array)` I get `1,2,3,4,5,6`. Is there a pythonic way to do this. Thanks.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There are so many questions about counting occurrences (and indeed, ways to do so in Python) that I feel like this question was barely researched. It's almost certainly a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

```
#List of data which has every item repeated except for 5 and 6
lst= [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4]

#This list comprehension prints a value in the list if the value only occurs once.
print [x for x in lst if lst.count(x)==1]
#Output
[5, 6]
```

Comment: @ppperry I added a couple of comments to explain it more. I thought it was a fairly basic list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the appropriately named *filter* method:

```
>>> i = [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4]
>>> filter(lambda x: i.count(x) == 1, i)
[5, 6]
```