# Find elements in list which occure only one time in list

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a function which return a list of elements which occur only once in a given list and it is working as expected but this is not what I want is there any built-in function or other method which do same functionalities without iterating:

```
def unique_items(ls):
    return [item for item in ls if ls.count(item)==1]

print(unique_items([1,1,1,2,3,2,4,5,4]))
```

Comment: How do you expect to know what's in the list if you don't iterate through it?

Comment: @nyov just like we sort list using built-in function I wanted to know is there any built-in function to find unique values from list

Comment: yes there is, `set()`, but you didn't say you want unique values. And to figure out the number of occurences in the list, IMHO you'll have to traverse it first. I could be wrong.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706863/return-the-number-that-occur-only-once-in-a-array-python

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2]
>>> c = Counter(a)
>>> c
Counter({1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1})
>>> [k for k, v in c.items() if v == 1]
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response sir but I said without iterating or using loop

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use an explicit loop, you can use `filter`:

```
def unique_items(ls):
    return list(filter(lambda s : ls.count(s) == 1, ls))

print(unique_items([1,1,1,2,3,2,4,5,4]))
```

Output:

```
[3, 5]
```

Comment: This is not optimal; the list gets iterated over each time `ls.count()` is called, so the time complexity is closer to `O(n2)` than necessary

Answer (score 1):

Comparing some options mentioned here:

```
def func_1(ls):
    return [
        item
        for item in ls
        if ls.count(item) == 1]

def func_2(ls):
    c = collections.Counter(ls)
    return [
        k
        for k, v in c.items()
        if v == 1]
```

Comparisson code:

```
import timeit
a_1 = [1,1,1,2,3,2,4,5,4]
a_2 = [1,1,1,2,3,2,4,5,4] * 100

for f in [func_1, func_2]:
    print(f.__name__)
    print(
        'short list',
        timeit.timeit(
            'f(a)',
            'from __main__ import {} as f, a_1 as a'.format(f.__name__),
            number=100))
    print(
        'long list ',
        timeit.timeit(
            'f(a)',
            'from __main__ import {} as f, a_2 as a'.format(f.__name__),
            number=100))
```

Results:

```
func_1
short list 0.00014933500006009126
long list  0.5417057829999976
func_2
short list 0.0005539439998756279
long list  0.0029211379996922915
```

So far, `func_2` is faster for large inputs and `func_1` is slightly faster for very short inputs.